# Echoing MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

I have been trying for the past while to echo out the result of a a MySQL query in PHP. I can't seem to get it to work so I am a bit lost. I know for a fact that the query works as I have done it in PHPMYADMIN and it is working fine, however whenever I load the webpage, nothing is outputted. For the purposes of this question I have generalized the things in the query as I obviously don't want anyone accessing my database. This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
    if (!$connect) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db('dbname')) {
        die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(row name) FROM `table`');
    if (!$result) {
        die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo mysql_result($result);

    mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

I look forward to your replies.

Comment: What about `echo "mysql_result($result)";`

Comment: MYSQL_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_result` need the second parameter (*The row number from the result that's being retrieved*).

```
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

**you have to change**

echo mysql_result($result);
**by**

```
echo mysql_result($result,0);
```

or you can use

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
echo mysql_result($result,0);
```

For more information, please give a look on http://www.php.net/mysql_result

or you can use mysql_fetch_row instead of mysql_result.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this following format:
Give your Sql command like this:

```
 $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(row name) as new_column_name FROM `table`');
```

then use this loop

```
while($fetched_values = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $fetched_values['new_column'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mysql_connect you have provided 4 parameters. it accepts 3 params

host, username and password. dbname is given inside `mysql_select_db`

as you can see from official docs. So remove the 4th param from mysql_connect function.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

http://php.net/function.mysql-connect

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

but these mysql_* function will be deprecated use mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

pass a row number as second parameter in mysql_result

echo mysql_result($result, 1);

or

use print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
where $result is your result resource

Answer (score 0):

if you have any doubt you may refer my following example program.

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_name', 'password', 'db_name');
if (!$connect) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('db_name')) 
{
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_query('SELECT (Tamil+English+Maths) as total FROM table_name');
if (!$row) 
{
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
while($fetched_row = mysql_fetch_array($row)){
echo $fetched_row['total'];
}

mysql_close($connect);
```

?>

here Tamil,English and Maths are the column values of my table